# Javascript editor only in <script> tag of jsp file

Tags: javascript, jsp, eclipse-kepler

I am using Eclipse Kepler and have installed plug-in editor for javascript (JSDT). It works for .js file. How can I use it also in a .jsp file only inside the `<script>` element? Example:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Private expenses</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {                        
                $('#submit').click(function(event) {  
                    var username=$('#user').val();
                 $.get('servlet-data-handler',{user:username},function(responseText) { 
                        $('#welcometext').text(responseText);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
</head>
```

The JSP Editor is used for the whole document. I want to use it only for the parts of the document that are outside of the `<script>` element, and inside use the JavaScript Editor. How to make such a configuration?

Comment: Why not just include the JS from a separate file? You'd get all the editor support you want and make the code cleaner. I've seen JSP files with a mix of HTML, JSP tags, CSS, inline Java and JavaScript and they're always a nightmare to read.

Comment: thanks @toniedzwiedz, that is certainly a better practice and viable workaround.
I wonder if the support for different editors in the same file was added.